# Handle jwt auth errors in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, error-handling, jwt, token

I'm working on a rest api project. 
I was struggling with an issue. As I get the token expiration error, the generated code will be something like this :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $this->checkForToken($request);

    try {
        if (! $this->auth->parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('jwt-auth', 'User not found');
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('jwt-auth', $e->getMessage(), $e, $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

This code is written in this file :

> vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Http/Middleware/BaseMiddleware.php

How can I return this as a JSON type?

Comment: `return response()->json(["type" => 'jwt-auth', "message" => $e->getMessage()])`

Comment: Or use `json_encode($e->getMessage())` and return it to the view or wherever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch that exception in your **App\Exceptions\Handler** class' render method and return a response formatted as json:

```
// Handler.php
// import the class of the exception you want to render a json response for at the top
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
...

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{   

  // if your api client has the correct content-type this expectsJson() 
  // should work. if not you may use $request->is('/api/*') to match the url.


  if($request->expectsJson()) 
  {

    if($exception instanceof UnauthorizedHttpException) {

      return response()->json('Unauthorized', 403);

    }

  }

  return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Comment: what's your mean of exception classes
i have this code in default :
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

Comment: you need to import the exceptions you will use in the render method. so in your case add `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;` to the top of Handler.php

Comment: didn't help completely but helped me to understanding what's happening , Thanks 2 U